Using Powershell to data drop a csv file from a WebEx API to SQL Server: Exception calling "WriteToServer" with "1" argument(s):
I am trying to drop WebEx meeting data to my company's SQL server. After running line by line, the csv data and datatable are loaded. However when I run the bulk copy method, it returns this error.

The given value of type String from the data source cannot be
converted to type int of the specified target column.

Each DestinationColumn,DestinationOrdinal,SourceColumn,andSourceOrdinal all return as -1.
What am I missing?
here is the attempt to perform the bulk copy:
try {
    $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dt)
    Write-Host "Data successfully inserted into the table."
}
 catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $_"
    foreach ($errorRecord in $_.Exception.Errors) {
        Write-Host "SQL Error: $($errorRecord.Message)"
    }
} finally {
    $bulkCopy.Close()

}
I have checked that all the column names align and have changed most of the data types in sql to variables as int's can be tricky. Currently only the meetingId is an int and start/end column name is datetime. Everything else is either a varchar or nvarchar.
I am looking for the data to show in the the SQL server but so far, only the column names are there.
Each column in the script have $dt.Columns.Add and rows are in my foreach loop with $dataRow.

The error is telling you that one of the column definitions in $dt is of type string, whereas the table schema on the SQL side is expecting an integer. Can you show us the code with which you defined the dt columns?

Please also show your code where you create the datatable

After running line by line, the csv data and datatable are loaded. This sounds wrong from the very start. Are you writing your own code to read the CSV file line by line and split it on commas instead of using the built-in Import-Csv cmdlet?

To properly troubleshoot will probably need more information - can you show a representative line from the csv, the “line by line” code that works, the code that builds $dt and schema of the sql table? The basic problem is pretty clear from the error messsge, but the root cause as to which column it is will be hiding in the details…
